# References on computational PDE (in fluid dynamics, solid mechanics, etc) that emphasize both rigorous analysis and coding

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, soft-question, na.numerical-analysis, applications

I'm interested in learning about **computational aspects of PDE and integro partial differential equations**.

In particular, I'd like to know some reference monographs that cover PDE and IPDE from  in **computational physics**, **computational fluid dynamics**, **computational solid mechanics**, **computational biology** (including biomodeling, genomics, neuroscience), **computational chemistry and pharmacology**.

I'd appreciate both *rigorous mathematical and numerical analysis*  and *extensive* use of *sample code written in MATLAB/Mathematica*.

---

Here are two related questions that I have checked out:

- [Reference request: numerical analysis of PDEs and integro partial differential equations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281979/reference-request-numerical-analysis-of-pdes-and-integro-partial-differential-e)
- [Books and resources on PDEs that use Mathematica and Matlab](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277002/books-and-resources-on-pdes-that-use-mathematica-and-matlab?noredirect=1&lq=1)